# Module is not found - Android Studio, ActionbarSherlock, SVN

Tags: svn, actionbarsherlock, android-studio

My app won't compile.

Looked at lots of workarounds, but none worked for me.

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

**libraries/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**AppName/settings.gradle**

```
include ":libraries:actionbarsherlock", ':app'
```

If this is a duplicate please let me know!

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There's an easier way to use ActionBarSherlock. Instead of downloading it as source, you can include it as a automatically managed library dependency using its Maven coordinates, and Android Studio will automatically download and include it at build time. To do that, delete it from your project and remove the dependency reference from your module's build file and the **settings.gradle** file, and instead, go to Project Structure > Dependencies, click the **+** button, choose **Library dependency**, and in the dialog that comes up, enter the Maven coordinates for the library: `com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar`. You should be good to go.

As an aside, your **libraries/build.gradle** file is redundant; it won't read it. I'd recommend deleting it.